Error in docker container: *Please install dotnet SDK*
I have a solution in dotnet 2.2 with microservice architecture.
and I also implement docker-compose for that.
Before today, it's working fine. But today I updated the Docker desktop application. After the Update project is not running.
Docker-Desktop: 4.30.0
Visual Studio 2022: 4.8.09032
and I also have dotnet SDKs.

and show the following warning in docker-container logs.

Why did this error occur?
And how to fix this issue?
